# maven does not show colors in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to display **colors** when I execute test but it does not work for spring 2

i tried

```
spring.output.ansi.enabled=always
```

still same result.

i tried this website:

[Enable Color in Spring Boot Test Console Log](https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/spring-boot/how-to-enable-color-in-spring-boot-console-log.html#comment-120303)

but get only "black and white", the colors never shows up

I have maven 3.5.2 and spring/boot 2

unitest result:
[image]
springboot tests result:
[image]

Comment: Whats the version of spring you are using?

Comment: Try adding these properties, spring.main.banner-mode=off 
spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS

Comment: "spring/boot 2.1.0"

Comment: @Santosh updated in my application.properties and same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your pom.xml configuration. Depending on which group/artifact you are using to run the `mvn verify`.

I am using the `org.codehaus.mojo` and I was never able to make it work, I switched to org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin and it worked for me.

Try this configuration and try again:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>post-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**EDIT:**
In addition, make sure you have:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it might be because of case sensitivity so change always to uppercase like below.

spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to use `spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS` (in my testing the value is case-insensitive, supporting `ALWAYS` or `always`).

The key for colored output for Spring Boot *tests* is to place this value in your **test** resource folder: `src/test/resources/application.properties`.

If you only place that property in the `src/main/...` folder, it won't apply to your tests.